# How to trigger the wrap of items in a ListView in Delphi?

Tags: listview, delphi, delphi-7

I have a ListView set to vsIcon. Each item is a image with a small text beneath. When I add many items they are wrapped for the width of the ListView (for example 5 items on a row). But when I change its width they are not wrapped again for the new width.

What I tried so far:

- ListView.Update;
- ListView.Refresh;
- ListView.Repaint;
- function ListView_Arrange(hwndLV: HWND; Code: UINT): Bool;
- function ListView_RedrawItems(hwndLV: HWND; iFirst, iLast: Integer): Bool;

I haven't tried sorting the items because I don't want them to be sorted. But most of the times they are sorted so sorting wouldn't help much (if it will wrap them, which I don't believe it will).

What I use now:

```
procedure TForm.WMExitSizeMove(var Message: TMessage);
var
   i, p: Integer;
   ListItem: TListItem;
   c: array of string;
   b: array of Boolean;
begin
   if Showing and (PreviousWidth <> Width) then
   begin
      p := ListView.ItemIndex;
      SetLength(c, ImageList.Count);
      SetLength(b, ImageList.Count);
      for i := 0 to ImageList.Count - 1 do
      begin
         c[i] := ListView.Items[i].Caption;
         b[i] := ListView.Items[i].Selected;
      end;
      ListView.Items.BeginUpdate;
      ListView.Clear;
      for i := 0 to ImageList.Count - 1 do
      begin
         ListItem := ListView.Items.Add;
         ListItem.Caption := c[i];
         ListItem.ImageIndex := i;
         ListItem.Selected := b[i];
      end;
      ListView.ItemIndex := p;
      ListView.Items.EndUpdate;
      SetLength(c, 0);
      SetLength(b, 0);
      PreviousWidth := Width;
   end;
   inherited;
end;
```

But, as you notice, it's not that fast for a large amount of items.
Could you please help me find a better way...?

Thank you.

I use Delphi 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The listview can do that for you automatically.
Somewhere in your code ( perhaps in formcreate) insert the following:

```
listview.IconOptions.AutoArrange := true;
```

Or you can set it in the properties window as well.

Comment: Thank you but it's not working.

Comment: I made a simple application with a ListView and a bunch of items. I anchored the ListView to the form and set AutoArrange to true and everything works as expected.   
Have you overridden any of the drawing events that might prevent the default draw from firing?

Comment: The drawing events weren't the problem but the ShowWorkAreas property was set to True. Seems like is working when is set to False. Who would of known... :D Thank you.